# Trying to optimize some looping code

Tags: objective-c, arrays, loops, optimization, enumeration

I have to NSArrays:

- _kundenArray - holding all customers (currently about 3000)
- _bestellungenMutArr - holding all orders (currently about 8000)

~~~~~

EDIT2 - added:

both my arrays get filled by parsing separate csv files, so initially I have no clue about any relationship between customers and orders.

~~~~~

For every customer I try to determine its orders, more specifically its last order (date).

I estimate that more than half of my customers do not have any orders, some have several, others a lot.

At the very beginning I had 2 nested loops, the outer one iterating over all customers, the inner one iterating over all orders. Which ended up in more than (3000 * 8000) comparisons (confer the attached code).

After some musing I realized that I have only valid orders, i.e. every order has a customer id and for every customer id i have an existing customer with the same id.
To reduce the overhead of the inner loop I ordered both my arrays according to their customer ids.

That implies that the first order(s) correspond to my first customers. E.g:

- _kundenArray[0] has customer with id **115**
- _bestellungenMutArr[0-3] has order with ids *24-27*, each ordered by customer **115**

Each corresponding order is then collected in an array until I reach an order, whose customer id does not correspond to my customer's id. I then exit (break) my loop, remove my collected orders from the array containing all the orders (_bestellungenMutArr) and proceed with the next customer.

Removal of the objects from the array is quite fast, as the objects are *ALL* at the beginning of the big array. (also see graphs stating the performance of the different array operations [here](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/array.html) at ridiculousfish.

Inspecting the Instrument's time profiler data, I found out that over 99% of the time is spent on the removal of the objects. Instruments output:
[image: Instrument's output for my "removeObjectsInArray"-approach]

I then came up with the idea to take advantage of the enumerateObjectsUsingBlock's index. Instead of using fast enumeration for the inner loop, I'm using block enumerator. To achieve the same reduction of overhead in my inner loop (i.e. never process an order twice I keep track of the index which I later use to have an offset for the next iteration (for the next customer). This way I circumvent the removal of objects from an array, which I thought might quite a nifty idea.

Inspecting the time profiler output it turned out it wasn't:
[image]

So using the variant removing objects from array by using removeObjectsInArray method (for about 1500 times) is about 8 times faster, than simply keeping track of an index?

Is this to be expected or am I missing something?

The array removal/fast enumeration variant:

```
- (void) determineLastOrders
{
    for (Kunde * kunde in _kundenArray)
    {
        NSMutableArray *bestellungenToRemove = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        /* go through all (remaining) orders (after the loop the matching will be removed) and determine the next ones to remove */
        for (Bestellung * bestellung in _bestellungenMutArr)
        {
            if ([[bestellung bestKdNr] isEqualToString:kunde.kdnr])
            {
                if ( kunde.lastOrder == nil)   
                {
                    kunde.lastOrder = _orangeDate;  //"init"
                }
                else if ([kunde.lastOrder compare:[bestellung bestDatum]] == NSOrderedAscending)
                {
                    kunde.lastOrder = [bestellung bestDatum];
                }
                //As this Bestellung already has had a date comparison (equal by kdnr)
                //we won't need to visit it again by our next customer
                [bestellungenToRemove addObject:bestellung];
            }
            else
            {   //as all orders are ordered by the customer id we can abort iteration
                //after we went past the current id
                break;
            }
        }
        [_bestellungenMutArr removeObjectsInArray: bestellungenToRemove];
    }
}
```

and the checking index / block enumeration variant:

```
- (void) determineLastOrders
{
    __block NSUInteger bestIndex = 0;
    for (Kunde * __block kunde in _kundenArray)
    {
        /* go through all (remaining) orders (after the loop the matching will be removed) and determine the next ones to remove */
        [_bestellungenMutArr enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: ^(Bestellung * bestellung, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
         {
            if (idx >= (bestIndex))
            {
                if ([[bestellung bestKdNr] isEqualToString:kunde.kdnr])
                {
                    if ( kunde.lastOrder == nil)
                    {
                        kunde.lastOrder = _orangeDate;  //"init"
                    }
                    else if ([kunde.lastOrder compare:[bestellung bestDatum]] == NSOrderedAscending)
                    {
                        kunde.lastOrder = [bestellung bestDatum];
                    }                
                }
                else
                {   //as all orders are ordered by the customer id we can abort iteration
                    //after we went past the current id
                    bestIndex = idx+1;
                    *stop = YES;
                }
            }
         }];
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: One other question just came to my mind. Currently - in my first code snippet, I always call the removeObjectsInArray method after each inner loop. If a customer has no orders, I remove an empty array (i.e. trying to remove nil?).
My guess is, that the method exits is instruction to do removal if an empty array is passed, so this is more efficient than checking my small array for contents every loop. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Why not use NSDictionary to store orders for particular customer? Key-Value pairs for NSDictionary can be "kunde.kdnr-NSArray-Of-Orders". This will allow getting all orders for a customer once, instead of iterating through complete array order set.

Comment: If this data were in Core Data it would be much easier to query for what you're looking for.

Comment: @gagarwall I am parsing two separate csv files. One containing all customers, the other containing all orders. At the beginning I have no clue, which order corresponds to which customer. So either way I have to loop through both to identify the relationships.

Comment: @EricAmorde Yes, I guess so; but to get my data in there the same problem applies, as already stated to gagarwal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second example is better, but you're still enumerating through more orders than you need to for each customer, since `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:...` starts at the beginning each time. (Unlike in your first code sample, where the array of orders shrinks for each customer.) Try using `enumerateObjectsAtIndexes:...` instead, passing an index set made with an NSRange beginning with `bestIndex`.

Or, you could just use a normal for loop: `for (NSUInteger i = bestIndex; i < [_bestellungenMutArr count]; i++)` which would probably be faster.

Comment: This is amazing! Using the normal loop the time consumption for the method dropped down 11ms which is over 50x faster than my best solution I had so far.
Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

one more level of optization:

```
int count = [_bestellungenMutArr count];
for (NSUInteger i = bestIndex; i < count; i++)
```

why?

now it will not loop through [_bestellungenMutArr count] every time.